# yii CGridView & Comparison Operators

Tags: php, yii

I want to limit the result of items displayed in a gridview by using comparison operators.

Something like:

```
$model->dateEnd >= date("Y-m-d");
```

Is there something that I can do in the controller to do so? Or does it have to be done in the search method of the model?

Answer (score 0):

You filter the results showing in your a CGridView by addition criteria to the data provider. For example:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
  'criteria'=>array(
    'condition'=>'dateEnd >= NOW()',
  ),
  'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>20,
  ),
));
```

The [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) docs have more info.

Comment: John Watson I currently have it filtered in a search method but just wondering if I could move it into my controller though.  I guess I could with the adding the dp to the controller if that is what it takes?  If not using comparison operators in the controller it is as simple as $model->dateEnd = date("Y-m-d"); so I was wondering if something like that would work for comparison operators also?

Comment: I think it should be in your controller.  Where do you have it currently?  The view?

Comment: Because it's a filter appropriate to a particular model (with a dateEnd field), but useful across many views and controllers (any view or controller that interacts or relates to that model), wouldn't a model "named scope" implementation make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a "parameterized named scope" that would be used with syntax similar to what you asked for:

```
$models->after($date);
```

The [Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) shows how to implement named scopes in your model like this:

```
public function after($date='2011-11-11')
{
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition'=>'dateEnd >=  :endDate',
        'params'   => array(":endDate"=>"%$date%")
        ));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: And you can combine multiple parameterized named scopes like this: `$models->after('2011-11-11')->before('2011-12-31')`